# Where browser store the Cache Item

Tags: asp.net

Hi all 
If i enable client side cache in my asp.net application where it store that cache controls in my computer  thanks

Regards
Nasir Islam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be differ from one browser to other, and from OS to Other.

In Microsoft Internet Explorer, the images are stored under a hidden folder under each users profile. The folder is C:\Documents and Settings(username)\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files.

if you want to view the cash in Firefox Just type "about:cache" into the address bar.

Comment: In version 13.0.1, this no longer seems to work. It just gives information about the entries themselves, not where it's stored.